# Incomparable types capture and int in Java streams allMatch()

Tags: java, java-8, x509certificate, x509

I have a X509 certificate. I'm trying to extract all the SANs from it. After that, I want to make sure that SAN is of type dNSName - that is the first entry in the list should be an integer with value 2. Ref- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectAlternativeNames()

The expression below fails to compile saying "Incomparable types capture and int"

`certificate.getSubjectAlternativeNames().stream().allMatch(x -> x.get(0) == 2)`

However, the following expression returns True.

`certificate.getSubjectAlternativeNames().stream().allMatch(x -> x.get(0).toString().equals("2"))`

I don't want to convert it to String and then match it to a string. I simply want an Integer comparison here. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

> I simply want an Integer comparison here.

You should be able to simply call `Object#equals` on the first element of the `List`:

```
certificate.getSubjectAlternativeNames()
           .stream()
           .allMatch(x -> x.get(0).equals(2))
```

Because the generic type of the `List` is a capture type `?`, the compiler won't be able to infer what type of `Object` is in it, and won't allow you to compare it to a primitive (directly).

```
List<List<?>> list = List.of(List.of(1, 2, 3));

System.out.println(list.stream().allMatch(x -> x.get(0).equals(1)));
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: To add to that: `List`s can only ever store Object types, never primitves. Comparing Objects to primitives with `==` is only possible in cases where unboxing of the object is possible. For this, the object's type must be statically deducible to be one of the boxed primitive type (`Integer`, `Long`, ...)

Comment: @WorldSEnder but if it is not statically deducible that the type of the collection’s elements is `Integer`, it’s quiet dangerous to use `equals`, as that will silently fail if the type does not match, e.g. if the elements are actually `Long` values. The better alternative is `x -> (Integer)x.get(0) == 1` which will make it apparent if the assumption about the element type is wrong.